# Total of Various Columns as a Separate Column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you help me out with an issue I have in Oracle?
Let's say I have a table that tells me about how many items were sold in each month, and looks like so:

| Item | January | February | March | April |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | 3 | 5 | 2 | 9 |
| TV | 10 | 12 | 16 | 14 |
| Camera | 22 | 25 | 20 | 27 |

What I need in the output is a table that would count the total number of items sold over the period, and would look like this:

| Item | January | February | March | April | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Computer | 3 | 5 | 2 | 9 | 19 |
| TV | 10 | 12 | 16 | 14 | 52 |
| Camera | 22 | 25 | 20 | 27 | 94 |

I am honestly not sure how to do that. Should I use grouping()?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you really want to use aggregation functions then you can unpivot, aggregate and then pivot ... but that will be computationally expensive when you can just use the `+` operator to add the columns.

Comment: Can a value be `null`, or will that always (and I mean **always**) be shown as 0? If the values can be `null` then you must take a bit of care, but other than that, use the `+` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use grouping at all just try to plus all columns as a new column `Total`.

```
SELECT T.*,
       (January + February + March + April) Total
FROM T
```